# How to detect an absent object in the mask image and remove it in the original image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, mask

Below are two images: image 1 is the binary image of the original image while image 2 is the 'masked' image. Image 2 is a center part (nucleus) of the blobs which I extracted for my segmentation purpose.

#### Image 1:

[image: binary image of the original image]

#### Image 2:

[image: 'masked' image]

My problem is, one of the blobs in image 2 is removed (as pointed with the grey-ish arrow on the removed blob), how can I *let* the original image know the absent object hence removing that whole blob entirely in image 1 (the blob mentioned as pointed with the grey-ish arrow)? It's like "no nucleus here, so you are not needed" kind of removal. Image 2 is some sort of a 'seed' image for Image 1.

The blobs in both images are not the same size as the blobs in image 1 is the cells and the blobs in image 2 is actually the nucleus of those cells.

I use `bwconncomp` on both images and the `NumObjects` is different (of course it is) in both images. How do I go from there using that information?

Please lend me a hand. Thanks so much!!

(I'm using MATLAB R2013a)

Comment: Just thinking out loud - how about you compute the centroid point of all objects in image 2 (you can round the coordinates if you like) and see which of these points "fall inside an object" (i.e. this pixel is white) in image 1 - when you hit a centroid point that does not belong, just fill-paint that region black in image 1. [This is one of the tools you can use](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#buoixjn-2_1) (if you have the image processing toolbox).

Comment: Thank you! Yes I do think about that, like treat each of them as a seed for original image, but I don't know how to put them in codes.

Comment: I also don't know the specifics of how to build this algorithm, so what? What's stopping you from finding out? ...or at least trying things until you succeed? Read the documentation and look in Google for things that are unclear. Consider that trial and error is part of the learning process.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive comments, I'm sorry if I appear to be the lazy folly who only aims to get codes without trying. I have searched everywhere I could to get answers before I post my question here. I need at least a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fortunately straightforward thanks to logical indexing.

```
%# label image 1
lblOne = bwlabel(image1);

%# identify labels overlapping with the seed
%# ">0" not needed if image2 is of class logical
labelsInSeed = lblOne(image2>0); 

%# remove all labels not overlappign with the seed from image 1
%# ensure we're not accidentially pick up label 0 (the background)
image1cleanedUp = ismember(lblOne, labelsInSeed(labelsInSeed>0));
```

Note that this approach might implicitly perform a "bwareaopen" on image 1, since it may not pick up isolated pixels at the periphery of the cells. Use `imclose` beforehand if you don't want that to happen.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works wonders! I thought I need to label Image2 as well. I already clean up the image with watershed and bwareaopen beforehand so that this process is just to remove the unwanted blobs and do nothing else. Thanks for the advice though!